# MPI and move semantics

Tags: c++, mpi, move-semantics

How safe is it to use C++11 move semantics with MPI objects?

Let's consider a small example:

```
#include <mpi.h>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    MPI_Init(nullptr, nullptr);

    int rank;
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank);

    if (rank == 0) {
        // create info object and set a key value pair
        MPI_Info info;
        MPI_Info_create(&info);
        MPI_Info_set(info, "key", "value");

        int size;
        MPI_Info_get_nkeys(info, &size);
        std::cout << "size: " << size << std::endl;

        // move into new object
        MPI_Info info2 = std::move(info);
        MPI_Info_set(info2, "kex2", "value2");

        MPI_Info_get_nkeys(info2, &size);
        std::cout << "size: " << size << std::endl;
    }

    MPI_Finalize();
}
```

How safe is the move construction? I.e. is such a move operation defined on MPI objects or undefined behavior?

Comment: not sure if I understood the question....see answer and let me know what I misunderstood

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Types either implement moving or they dont in which case a move is nothing but a copy. Trying to move something that doesnt move is not undefined behaviour.

Remember that `std::move` alone merely casts to a r-value reference but does not move by itself.

Comment: Well I just had an error in my reasoning.
I somehow thought if you compile the MPI C code with a C++ Compiler all structs will get a default move constructor (if possible, e.g. no other constructors are defined), which in turn could potential screw things up.

Comment: MPI objects are opaque handlers, that are generally implemented as `int` by MPICH and pointers in Open MPI. /* disclaimer, I am not a C++ developer */

Comment: @GillesGouaillardet the last time I used MPI was long time before c++11, so I tried to keep the answer generic. If they are just handles, I wouldnt be too surprised when they dont bother to move at all